# jQuery :visible and :hidden not working with ifs in onmouseover and onmouseout

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

```
<div id="body" onmouseover="if ($('div#menu').is(':visible')) {$('div#menu:visible').hide('blind', { direction: 'left' }, 5000);}">
```

This is not working at all!
[Link to an example for this topic; (my website as of February 25 2012)](http://lbert.tk)

Comment: Inline JS is not the way to go, that being said, you have of course included jQuery UI when trying to use hide() and show() with directions and effects?

Comment: Yes, it works when I do not have the 'if' statements. But if they are not there, then many glitches occur with the animations repeating themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understood you now, this should be exactly what you want, just without those messy inline-javascript. I used the jQuery hoverIntent plugin (http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)

http://jsfiddle.net/FcdTw/

Comment: I implemented this into the site, but it is not working.

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div#lbert').hoverIntent(function() {
    if ($('div#menu').is(':hidden')) {
        $('div#menu').show('blind', {
            direction: 'left'
        }, 2000);
    }
}, function() {});
$('div#body').hoverIntent(function() {
    $('div#menu').hide('blind', {
        direction: 'left'
    }, 2000);
}, function() {});​
});
</script>

Comment: Did you include jQuery and the hoverIntent plugin? Don't forget to put the jQuery code into:  `$(function(){/*code here*/});`

Comment: I just took a look at the website. The jQuery isn't included properly, try to add `type="text/javascript"` to the `<script...>`-Tag and, most important, **include jQuery BEFORE the hoverIntent plugin!**

Comment: The last line in your script is `)};`, should be `});`. I made one last change to the script and uploaded it to my webspace, it's working for me: http://canals.ch/lbert/

Comment: No problem. You nearly got it on lbert.tk, just missing the if-statement in the second event.

Comment: Again, thanks. Added the if :visible for #body hoverIntent event.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery events instead of inline stuff:

```
$('#body').hover(function () {
    // Mouse over
    $('#menu').show();
}, function () {
    // Mouse out
    $('#menu').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to show your menu when the mouse hovers #body or #lbert?

So you should hide it first...?

```
div#menu {
  background: #EDEDED;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #A2A2A2;
  width: 98.5%;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: I want it so that it shows at first until the #body onmouseover event, and then hide it if and only if #menu is still visible. To show the menu, I want to toggle only #lbert and only if #menu is not visible. So the if statements are necessary.

Comment: Take a look at the jQuery hoverIntent plugin.
http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

That should prevent the animation glitches so you don't need the if statements!